# What is the meaning of _database_id field in Skygear?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, skygear

my team is using Skygear.io as project backend. And we found that all records with non-empty `_database_id` field value will be unable to be retrieved by running queries. It's seems a pre-defined field by Skygear platform but it is lack of information about how to use it. All records with empty value are working as normal.

So, I would like to ask,

1. What is the meaning of a `_database_id` field?
2. How do we make use of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. `_database_id` is a reserved field for Skygear to identify whether the record is saved in public DB or private DB. You may refer to [this guide](https://docs.skygear.io/guides/advanced/database-schema/).

For the concept of public DB and private DB, you may also have a look on [this guide](https://docs.skygear.io/guides/cloud-db/basics/js/).

Comment: Thanks. It saved me.